# Iterating through a for loop with the size of an array

Tags: python

I want my program to be able to print out the sum of all numbers below n that are divisible by 3 and also 5.

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys
import math
arr = []
arr3 = []
arr5 = []
tn = 1
sum1 = 0 
sum2 = 0

t = int(input("How many test cases do you have? ").strip())

while t < 1 or t > 10**5:
    print("go again, the number is not in the range")
    t = int(input("How many test cases do you have? ").strip())

for i in range(t):
    n = int(input("What number do you want to test? ").strip())
    arr.append(n)
    
for x in range (0, len(arr)):
    for b5 in range (0, arr[x], 5)
        sum1 = sum1 + b5
    for b3 in range (0, arr[x], 3)
        sum2 = sum2 + b3
    sum = sum1 + sum2
    print(sum)
```

My idea was to let the secondary for loops iterate through the given number in increments and print each iteration into the sum. Somehow I cannot pass an argument into the for loop in the way that I present here. How do I make this approach work?

Edit:

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys
import math
arr = []
arr3 = []
arr5 = []
tn = 1
sum1 = 0 
sum2 = 0

t = int(input().strip())

while t < 1 or t > 10**5:
    print()
    t = int(input().strip())

for i in range(t):
    n = int(input().strip())
    arr.append(n)
    
for x in range (0, len(arr)):
    sum1 = 0
    sum2 = 0
    mo5 = arr[x]%5
    mo3 = arr[x]%3
    if mo5 == 0 or mo3 == 0:
        arr[x] = arr[x]-1
 
    for b5 in range (0, arr[x], 5):
        sum1 = sum1 + b5
        print(b5)
    for b3 in range (0, arr[x], 3):
        sum2 = sum2 + b3
    sum = sum1 + sum2
```

I am also trying to exclude the integer located at arr[x], since the sum of the divisible numbers must be from divisible numbers below the number arr[x]. When I print out the result for 100, then it shows 0, 5, 0, 5, ... 95. This brings it to a total of 100 again. Why does this happen?

Comment: So if the `t` value is 10**4, you'll input it one by one. What do you mean by `result for 100`? Please, give example input and expected output.

Comment: The constraint is just a general necessity and not be viewed at in a practical sense. If there were so many inputs for t, then it would likely be a list that would be passed into an array with a for loop. The result for n = 100 is what I mean.

Comment: If `t = 10` and `n = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, so `b3 = [3,6,9]` and `b5 = [5,10]` then the result is `33`, is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: The total should come to 23 as only the divisible numbers of 3 and 5 below the number n will be added together.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems correct - but it seems u have a couple of syntax errors if you're using python
You also have to re-initialize `sum1` & `sum2` between test cases. Right now you get the total sum of all `arrs` rather than `arr[x]`-hopefully that makes sense. You also have to remove duplicate numbers from the sum. For instance, if you're getting the sum of all numbers up to 20 - you'll end up adding 15 twice as it is divisible by 3 and 5. So the inner for loops will add it twice to the sum. So you'll need to remove 15 to get rid of duplicates.

```py
for x in range(len(arr)): #by default range starts at o. therefore, range(len(arr)) = range(0, len(arr)) 
    sum1 = 0 # you forgot to initialize sum1
    sum2 = 0 # you forgot to initialize sum2
    duplicates = 0 #you have to remove duplicates from the answer
    for b5 in range (0, arr[x], 5): #you have to add the colons here
        sum1 = sum1 + b5
    for b3 in range (0, arr[x], 3): #you have to add the colons here
        sum2 = sum2 + b3
    for dup in range(0, arr[x], 3*5): # removes duplicates from the final sum
        duplicates = duplicates + dup
    sum = sum1 + sum2 - duplicates 
    print(sum)
```

This is an O(n^2) solution - you can drop it down to O(n) using a little bit of math.

You'll notice that the inner for loops can be represented using the formula `sum(n)=Σd*i=d*Σi`-where the summation starts at `i = 0`, end at `⌊(n-1)/d⌋` and `d` is the divisor (in the case of your question `d=3 or 5`).

```py
for b5 in range (0, arr[x], 5):
    sum1 = sum1 + b5
```

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation)

There is a very common summation formula that is commonly used to convert summations into a closed-form expression (something with finite steps - which is O(1))

`Σi=n*(n+1)/2`

In the case of the inner loop - it would be `sum(n) = d*(⌊(n-1)/d⌋)*(⌊(n-1)/d⌋+1)/2`.

let,

`f(n,d) = (⌊(n-1)/d⌋+1)/2`

Therefore, the solution to your problem would be `f(n,3)+f(n,5)-f(n,3*5)`

Which would convert the inner for loops from O(n) to O(1). Which, means your entire solution would be O(n).

I'll let you figure out the code on your own. However, theoretically, there is a better solution; such that as `arr` grows indefinitely the work scales linearly rather than quadratically.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This really helped a lot. I forgot the colons and now with the initialized sum variables it works just fine. I found though that my program still doesn't quite do what it is supposed to, as it doesn't exclude arr[x]. I put my further work into the main question for you to see. It will also take some time to understand your math. Thank you a lot though, this answer is gold.

Comment: - Can you elaborate on what you mean by excluding arr[x]
- If you have any questions about the math - I would happily love to answer
- I had to update the answer, as the initial solution didn't account for duplicates. As in both for loops will add the same number if they are both divisible by 3 & 5.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

- You are using the `len` function to get the length of `arr`, but you haven't defined `arr` or assigned any values to it. You need to define `arr` and assign a list of numbers to it before you can iterate over it.
- You are using the `range` function incorrectly in your `for` loops. The `range` function takes a start value, an end value, and an optional step value, but you are only providing the end value and step value. You need to provide the start value as well.
- You are using the `b5` and `b3` variables to store the values from the `range` function, but you are not using them to calculate the sum of the numbers that are divisible by 3 and 5. You need to use these variables to calculate the sum.
- You are defining the `sum1` and `sum2` variables inside the for loops, but you are not initializing them to 0 before adding the numbers to them. You need to initialize these variables to 0 before adding the numbers to them.

Here is how you could fix your code:

```
    arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]  # Define the list of numbers
    for x in range(0, len(arr)):  # Iterate over the list of numbers
    sum1 = 0  # Initialize sum1 to 0
    sum2 = 0  # Initialize sum2 to 0
    for b5 in range(0, arr[x], 5):  # Iterate over the numbers in increments of 5
        sum1 = sum1 + b5  # Add the number to sum1
    for b3 in range(0, arr[x], 3):  # Iterate over the numbers in increments of 3
        sum2 = sum2 + b3  # Add the number to sum2
    sum = sum1 + sum2  # Calculate the sum
    print(sum)  # Print the sum
```

Comment: Sorry, this is just a part of the code. I will add the whole thing to the main question.

Comment: I thought that the range function works in such a way that if only one parameter is there, it is the end value, if there is two, then it is start and end value and only if it is three, then it is the increment. Is that wrong and what is right? I also define the sum and print it out within the primary for loop, because this iteration goes over an amount of entries within the array, that has previously been defined, so that I need the sums to be printed out x times.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Array with input number (Eg. `arr = [12, 15, 4]` )
2. Iterate over the created Array
3. In `for` loop check if number are divisible by 3 and 5

Sample code:

```
    arr = [12, 15, 4]
    total = 0
    
    for num in arr:
        if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
            total = total + num
    
    print(total) # 15
```

Comment: Using `sum` as a variable is a bad idea since it [is a builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). In fact it would be very handy here with something like `sum(num for num in arr if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0)`

Comment: I think this program doesnt give the desired output. The biggest problem I have is that I want to use an element of the array as the end value of the range function. The program should give me the added sum of all numbers that exist within a number that are divisible by 3 and 5 combined. So for 10 it would be 3,5,6,9 adding up to 23.

Comment: @Mark changed variable name from ```sum``` to ```total```

Comment: @Pascal Barthelmäs > As per your last comment you mentioned that when you give for example N = 10, you want sum 23 that mean you want number which is divisible by 3 or 5 . but in problem description you mentioned ---> _**I want my program to be able to print out the sum of the all numbers below n that are divisible by 3 and also 5._**

Comment: @Pascal Barthelmäs Please help to clear what you want 
 Sum of number which is divisible by 3 or 5 **OR**
Sum of number which is divisible by 3 and 5

Comment: I need the program to give me the sum of all numbers, the ones that are divisible by 3 and the ones that are divisible by 5.

Answer (score -1):

```
arr = []
arr3 = []
arr5 = []
tn = 1
sum1 = 0 
sum2 = 0

t = int(input("How many test cases do you have? ").strip())

while t < 1 or t > 10^5:
    print("go again, the number is not in the range")
    t = int(input("How many test cases do you have? ").strip())

for i in range(t):
    n = int(input("What number do you want to test? ").strip())
    arr.append(n)
    
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] % 3 == 0:
        arr3.append(arr[i])
    elif arr[i] % 5 == 0:
        arr5.append(arr[i])  

for i in range(len(arr3)):
    sum1 = sum1 + arr3[i] 
for i in range(len(arr5)):
    sum2 = sum2 + arr5[i] 
sum = sum1 + sum2 

print(sum)
```

Comment: I dont see this code working. It gives me very odd outputs. As far as I can see it will also only output the var "sum" only once, while it has to be printed out "t" times.

Comment: I remove some print functions, now try again.

Comment: Can you give me your output?

Comment: The output is 100 and 110.